# Assigning dbcontext object to label

Tags: c#, dbcontext

I have a dbcontext object from a table that I'm trying to assign to a label, but the page is blank and the label doesn't show the output. How can I successfully assign a label on button click so that the table data is visible? The object I'm referring to is aMessage.highScoreEasy

```
    protected void myScoresButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num = 2;
        int num1 = 5;
        int num2 = 6;
        easyScoreLabel.Text = num.ToString();
        mediumScoreLabel.Text = num1.ToString();
        hardScoreLabel.Text = num2.ToString();
        gameOverLabel.Visible = false;

        warningLabel.Visible = false;
        using (projectDBEntities1 dbcontext = new projectDBEntities1())
        {
            message aMessage = new message();
            endGameScoreLabel.Visible = true;
            int parsedScoreLabel = 3; 
            aMessage.highScoreEasy = parsedScoreLabel;

            if (!Int32.TryParse(easyScoreLabel.Text, out parsedScoreLabel))
            {
                // The parsing failed, maybe notify the user of an invalid value

                endGameScoreLabel.Text = aMessage.highScoreEasy.ToString();
                welcomeUsernameLabel.Text = "Welcome" + aMessage.userName;

                aMessage.userName = nameTextBox.Text;

                dbcontext.messages.Add(aMessage);
                dbcontext.SaveChanges();


            }

            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a debugger. Press F9 to set a break point and F5 to debug.

Comment: I've tried that, but nothing comes up. I don't think anything should be wrong because this line of code aMessage.userName = nameTextBox.Text; works no problem, so it should be pulling data from the database table

Comment: Neither your comment nor your code make sense to me. You are assigning the forms data to your database, that is not pulling from the database. Please use a debugger and go through your code step by step and check if it's actually doing what you want it to do.